# Facing an error in intellij Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5

Tags: java, xml, selenium, maven

Here it is my POM.xml. While running a test case I am getting plugin error in intellij  "Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5". So what I need to do for resolving an error.
I need to install any specific version of apache?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>mobile-automation-framework</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MobileAutomationFramework</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <build>
        <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true</argLine>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>"testng.xml"</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>-->
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!--<systemPropertyVariables>
                        <property>
                            <invokeDriver>${invokeDriver}</invokeDriver>
                        </property>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-configuration2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.saucelabs/sauce_java_common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce_java_common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.saucelabs/sauce_testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce_testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.23</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am getting plugin error in intellij  "Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5". So what I need to do for resolving an error.
I need to install any specific version of apache?

Comment: First make only a single definition of maven-surefire-plugin. Remove the dependency to maven-surefire-report-plugin which is simply wrong.